# 1151: A conflict exists with definition, i dont understnad

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am having an error 1151 with AS3 
it says 
1151: A conflict exists with definition founditems in namespace internal. 
I don't understand what I have to change
here it the script I am having the error with 
var founditems:Number = 0;

the full script is below 
THANKS :D

```
stop();

inventoryknife.alpha = 0;
inventoryaxe.alpha = 0;
inventoryesports.alpha = 0;


esports.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, objectFound);
axe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, objectFound);
knife.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, objectFound);

var founditems:Number = 0;


can1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
can1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
can1.buttonMode = true;

can2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
can2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
can2.buttonMode = true;

can3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
can3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
can3.buttonMode = true;

can4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
can4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
can4.buttonMode = true;


brick1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
brick1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
brick1.buttonMode = true;

brick2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
brick2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
brick2.buttonMode = true;

brick3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
brick3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
brick3.buttonMode = true;

brick4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
brick4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
brick4.buttonMode = true;

brick5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
brick5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
brick5.buttonMode = true;

brick6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
brick6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
brick6.buttonMode = true;

brick7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
brick7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
brick7.buttonMode = true;

brick8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
brick8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
brick8.buttonMode = true;

brick9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
brick9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
brick9.buttonMode = true;

brick10.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
brick10.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
brick10.buttonMode = true;

crate1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
crate1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
crate1.buttonMode = true;

crate2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
crate2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
crate2.buttonMode = true;

crate3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
crate3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
crate3.buttonMode = true;


crate4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
crate4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
crate4.buttonMode = true;

tile1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
tile1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
tile1_mc.buttonMode = true;




{
var inventoryName:String = "inventory" + event.target.name;
var inventoryItem:DisplayObject = getChildByName(inventoryName);
event.target.alpha = inventoryItem.alpha = 100;
founditems ++;
event.target.alpha = 0;
if(founditems == 3)
{
door2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, escapeRoom);
}
}
```

Comment: Just add public. like this. 
`public var founditems:Number = 0;`

Comment: you have multiple object with that same name 'founditems', that is forbidden and your code will not compile until all your object have unique names. That includes: library export names, class names, variable names, etc ... everything that has a name must have a unique name. To Yasuyuki: adding public modifier is forbidden here and will cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in namespace internal. You write code on timeline (very bad practice) it maybe in another keyframe at the same frame # that variable is already defined. Or you may have some instance on stage with the same instance name...